# Is there any difference between "all students", "all the students" and "all of the students"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, plural-forms

1. All students in the school participated in the meeting.
2. All the students in the school participated in the meeting.
3. All of the students in the school participated in the meeting.

Are they all grammatically correct?  Is there any difference between the three?

Answer (score 1):

"All the students" and "all of the students" mean the same thing regardless of context.

When you qualify all three with "in the school", they become interchangeable. But without that qualifier, "all students" would refer to all students everywhere, and the other two would refer to some previously specified group of students.

An example of an exception: say a principal/headmaster makes an announcement addressed to "all students". Of course he means all students in the school—he's talking to the students under his authority and within the scope of whatever mechanism disseminates the announcement.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the three examples in the question is grammatically correct, and each seems quite natural to me. In these uses, there is no significant difference of meaning between them.

Answer (score 0):

All 3 examples are grammatically correct and have the same meaning. In terms of usage, the first one may be preferred for announcements e.g.

> All students please report to the auditorium

But otherwise there is no distinct different at all!